# Add a horizontal status indicator in android

Tags: java, android

Can Someone please help me out, in android studio there is only one default status indicator(Progress bar) that is vertical. I want to add a horizontal status indicator in my app please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this style to your `ProgressBar`, make sure you don't forget to add `wrap_content` to your `layout-height` attribute.

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

Also if you would need this, there is a nice option to make your ProgressBar to look like a loading bar, you need just to add this line to your ProgressBar layout:

```
android:indeterminateOnly="true"
```